# how to safely eval an urlencode-ed dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, urldecode

I should communicate with an online service that sends me the following data urlencoded:

```
data_to_process = {...}
args = {'args0': data_to_process, 'action': 'save'}

result = urllib2.urlopen(..., urllib.urlencode(args), ...)
```

The main data of interest is stored in the `data_to_process` dictionary. I would like to get back the original dictionary that's supposed to  contain only string, numeric and boolean values. How can you achieve this?

I've tried

```
eval(dict_str,{'__builtins__': None})
```

but this fails for `False` values (and who knows what else).

thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> test = repr({"ham": True, 42: "spam", "foo": "bar"})
>>> test
"{42: 'spam', 'foo': 'bar', 'ham': True}"
>>> literal_eval(test)
{42: 'spam', 'foo': 'bar', 'ham': True}
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that the service isn't sending you JSON? In which case you can parse it using the built-in `json.loads()` function (since Python 2.6).

Comment: yes, I'm sure, I have access to the original code (it's an OSS project), but I'm not a committer, and they won't change the behavior.